# C#: Declaring a constant variable for datatype to use

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible somehow to define a constant that says what datatype to use for certain variables, similar to generics? So in a certain class I would have something like the following:

```
MYTYPE = System.String;

// some other code here

MYTYPE myVariable = "Hello";
```

From the principle it should do the same as generics but I don't want to write the datatype every time the constructor for this class is called. It should simply guarantee that for two (or more) variables the same datatype is used.

Comment: What’s wrong with generics? You don’t like them because of longish constructors? Wrap them in `Classes` with a short name… 
`class Blub : VeryLongClass<AndLongType>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you *can* use a `using` directive:

```
using MYTYPE = System.String;
```

However, that isn't really like a typedef - in particular, this code is now perfectly valid:

```
MYTYPE x = "hello";
string y = "there";
x = y;
```

The compiler knows they're still the same type.

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, particularly here:

> I don't want to write the datatype every time the constructor for this class is called.

What do you mean?

Note that using directives are specific to a source file, not to a whole project.

Comment: I meant that I don't want to define the datatype to use in the constructor (as it is the case with a generic class). The using directive is exactly what i searched for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1225775: It's still not clear what you mean about the constructor, to be honest. A full example of what you were trying to achieve and what you meant about generics would have made this *much* clearer - something to bear in mind for next time.

Comment: When I would call a constructor for a class using generics I would have to say: MyObject<String> mo = new MyObject<String>() for example. But that would mean that there can exist more instances of MyObject<T> with different datatypes for T. For example I could say in the next line: MyObject<Integer> mo2 = new MyObject<Integer>(). That is not what I wanted because I want the type (for which I now use the using directive) is the same for all instances of this object.

Comment: @user1225775: In that case it's not clear to me why generics need to get involved at all...

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with a `using` alias:

```
using MyType = System.String;
```

however, only on a per-file basis. Frankly, it is useful for making a short alias to some complex composite generic type (I'm thinking of ["Owin"](http://pastie.org/3431403) etc), but other than that, generics are more versatile.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an alias:

```
using System;
using MYTYPE = System.String;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MYTYPE f = "Hello";
        Console.WriteLine(f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with a [*using alias directive*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

edit: beaten by a couple of seconds..